# Discord Bot to notify when twitch streams are live with JS

Tags: javascript, stream, bots, twitch, discord.js

I am trying to create a discord bot that notifies people when a channel goes live. I have found similar questions with answers but for some reason jquery does not seem to work and I am required to use getJSON.

Here is my index.js file.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const bot = new commando.Client();

const BotToken = "bottoken";
const TwitchClientID = "twitchclientID";
const TwitchURL = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/channelname";
const channelName = "channelname";

bot.registry.registerGroup('random', 'Random');
bot.registry.registerDefaults
bot.registry.registerCommandsIn(__dirname + "/commands");

bot.login('login'); 

bot.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.content === "!Live") {
        getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/channelname", function(err, res) {
            if (res.stream == null) {
                mybot.reply(message, "currently not live");
            } else {
                mybot.reply(message, "currently live");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have also tried jQuery.getJSON and $.getJSON. They all compile but when I do !Live the bot crashes and gives getJSON is not defined.

Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.1.0",
    "discord.js-commando": "^0.9.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why I cant get getJSON to work as this solution should work. Any help is appreciated, sorry if it seems like a silly question, I'm new to js and using other API's.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Are you importing jQuery?

Comment: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at CommandoClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\ScoreBoar\index.js:19:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at CommandoClient.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle 
(more)

Comment: I tried importing with var script = document.createElement('script');
 
script.src = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

But got document undefined then.

Comment: I got it to work with npm install get-json, was previously doing npm install getJSON. The bot still doesnt work for its intended purpose though :(

Answer (score 0):

`mybot.reply(message, "currently not live");`

This would be incorrect, you didn't define 'mybot'

Use this instead:

`message.reply("Currently not live");`